An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']
i am trying to build Apk for my flutter app but got error below

What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']


Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader'.
Could not load compiled classes for script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\native_plugin_loader.groovy' from cache.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

this is my setting.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}


plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.0" apply false //7.3.0
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
}

include ":app"`
`



This is my gradle-wrapper.properties
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
#7.6 


try change one line:
 pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.0" apply false //7.3.0
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
}

include ":app"`


when i used this i got a new error below                                                            * What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']

Included build 'C:\Users\PC\Downloads\classfied\version 1\eClassify\android\packages\flutter_tools\gradle' does not exist.


show me gradle-wrapper.properties, please

**#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
#7.6 **

try change to 7.5
